# Convert mysql column from varchar to varbinary gets a "table is full" error

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a lot of records (33 million) and I have a field that is a VARCHAR(255) and I want to convert it to VARBINARY(32).

everytime I try to do it I get the following error:

> ERROR 1114 (HY000): The table '#sql-7a72_8' is full.

This is the query I use:

```
alter table mytable modify myfield VARBINARY(32);
```

I have enough space on my drive (more than 12 GB which is the same size of my entire database)  so I am sure it is not a disk space issue.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

First find out what the value of the either `tmpdir` OR `innodb_tmpdir` variable is, which one to look at depends on which engine you are using:

InnoDB:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_tmpdir';
```

MyISAM:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'tmpdir';
```

Then check to verify this path has enough space to work.  An example would be, you have a table with 2GB of data and innodb_tmpdir is configured to `/tmp`. If the /tmp volume is configured to 512MB, MySQL likely won't have enough space to work with as it uses the tmpdir for temporary sort files.

I would recommend against your approach here as you could cause data loss or corruption.  Instead I would recommend adding a VARBINARY column to your table, populate it with data that you explicitly convert to BINARY.  Then drop the old column and rename the new column to the old column's name. It would look something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN myfield2 VARBINARY(32) AFTER myfield;
```

Since it looks like you want to truncate the column to a max of 32 characters the update statement to populate myfield2 would look like this:

```
UPDATE mytable SET myfield2 = CAST(LEFT(myfield, 32) AS BINARY);
```

Once you are happy with the results you can drop the old column:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DROP COLUMN myfield;
```

Then rename the new column:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME COLUMN myfield2 TO myfield;
```

I would also strongly advise both taking a backup and verifying the backup is good.  Restore the backup to another MySQL instance first.  Attempt the change on this second test instance.  This way you can insure that any changes you make are going to be exactly how you expect them.